# Function Return Assoc Array

Tags: php, arrays, function

So i have the below function but for some reason when I use it in a page it does not return the assoc array. If i print_r on the array inside the function it prints out the array but when I call the function/array on a page it does not work.  It's blank.  Not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
function fetch_one($Table, $PK) {
    include ("pdo_connection.php");
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `'.$Table.'` WHERE PK = ? LIMIT 1';
    //echo $sql;
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $PK = (int)$PK;
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $PK);
    $stmt->execute();
    $View = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $View;   
}
```

on the page itself i have

```
fetch_one($table, $pk);
print_r($View)
```

and it returns nothing.

Comment: Process the result of the function instead, $view var isn't available outside the function.

Comment: `fetch_one($table, $pk);` Maybe because you don't assign the return value?!

Comment: @raina77ow can you provide and example below.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run it you have to assign the value to a variable or else use it.  Either

```
$x = fetch_one($table, $pk);
print_r($x);
```

or

```
print_r(fetch_one($table, $pk));
```

Comment: Thank you Peter.  Simple fix.